# How to optimize 2000GB Git data

Tags: git

We are using git as a data warehouse, and the data now exceeds 2000GB. Each commit time will be very long, and then the local pull time is also very long and gc will cause excessive memory. Is there any strategy to optimize such a large amount of data?
[image]

Thank you for your reply. We have seen this solution and it does not seem to suit our situation. The reason why we pull the data locally is because the local program needs to quickly read the required data from the 2000G data at any time, and the time does not exceed 20ms. In fact, we are doing picture recognition. The central storage is training-generated data (these data are incremental and can be increased at any time). Because the picture recognition program is distributed, if the data is decentralized through the network, the data will be identified very slowly Concurrency is not high, so we need to put these picture models locally to improve recognition speed and concurrency.

Comment: I think you should create multiple warehouses now because you are relying on other's server.

Comment: Thank you, we have considered this plan, but it will make our program more complicated

Answer (score 3):

If you're storing large files in  your git repository you can use Git Large File Storage.

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio
>   samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git,
>   while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or
>   GitHub Enterprise.

https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: This can come in handy if moving migrating to git lfs https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/326

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The word limit for this reply is limited. Please see the description of the problem